# Apache Beam 2.12.0 with Java 11 support?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Does Apache Beam 2.12.0 support Java 11, or should i go still stick with a stable Java 8 SDK as for now?

I see the site recommends Python 3.5 with Beam 2.12.0 as per the documentation, compared to other higher Python versions. How much compartible it is with Java 11 at this time. So, would a stable version would be still Java 8 to go with Apache Beam 2.12.0. 
I faced few build issues when using Beam 2.12.0 with Java 11.

Comment: I was able to get a Beam SDK 2.17 job running on Dataflow + Java 11, by using following this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54764118/1046584

Answer (score 5):

**UPDATE**: Beam compatibility with Java 11 is introduced in version **2.29.0** *released on 2021-04-27*.

---

Original Answer:

Beam officially doesn't support Java 11, it has only experimental support starting from release 2.12. All artifacts are built with Java 8 but you can try to build and run your Java 11 code against them, though, there is no guarantee about that since work still in progress. One of the stoppers is that backends still don't not support Java 11. So, it's recommended to stick with Java 8 for production use cases for the moment.

For the reference, it was detailed discussion about that recently on dev@: [Java 11 compatibility question](https://lists.apache.org/thread.html/861920911d6130228458dd10c47828dd77ee5768cf15b3a6de2c21c4@%3Cdev.beam.apache.org%3E), and there is a Jira issue where the progress is tracked: [BEAM-2530](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-2530). So, feel free to report the issues that you had with Java 11.

Comment: Thank you. I was able to build the project, but when trying to create a Dataflow template(google cloud dataflow) i faced issues.

Comment: If it's possible for you then I'd suggest to stay with Java 8 for now until Java 11 will be officially supported in Beam